# Unit testing binary search

Tags: python

I'm having some difficulty implementing a modified version of binary search (it just needs to check if there is a 1 in the sub list, and then continue searching until it returns the index).

Currently the code I've come up with is:

```
def binary_search(inList):
    low = 0
    high = len(inList) -1
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low+high)//2
        upper = inList[mid:high]
        lower = inList[low:mid-1]
        if any(lower):
            inList = lower
            high = mid-1
        elif any(upper):
            inList = upper
            low = mid
        else:
        return mid

        assert low < high
    return -1
```

It seems to work for a couple of iterations of the loop, but then it returns empty lists, and fails. I've tested the function with the following input:

```
l = [0 for x in range(256)]
l[123] = 1
```

I've also noticed that some of the bins are lost when the list is decimated.

How would I go about creating a test suite, that will catch these problems and let me extend this algorithm to other input sets (e.g. a 1 in both halves, two 1's next to each other etc).

Comment: In your list slicing, you're chopping off the last element. The second index in the slice is the upper limit, non-inclusive limit. Think of the second index as "up to but not including index number n". So, high should initially be `high = len(inList)`, lower should be `lower = inList[low:mid]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man you're asking like three questions in one, but here goes nothing.

To create a testsuit simply write a few good examples and assert that they work, so something like:

```
from binary_search import binary_search

# Test a basic case
inlist = [0] * 256
inlist[123] = 1
assert binary_search(inlist) == 123

# Test a case with odd len
inlist = [0] * 99
inlist[20] = 1
assert binary_search(inlist, 20)

# Test the case with no 1s
inlist = [0] * 256
assert binary_search(inlist) == -1

# It's good to test corner cases just in case
inlist = [0] * 256
inlist[0] = 1
assert binary_search(inlist) == 0
inlist = [0] * 256
inlist[255] = 1
assert binary_search(inlist) == 255
```

You might want to consider using something like nose or the unittest module to help you organize your tests, but in any case the idea is to run the tests every time you change your code to make sure it's working. If you add new feature to your code, for example allowing to search for multiple 1s in the list, you'll want to add tests for that behavior.

You might already know this, but just in case I wanted to mention that this is a pretty poor algorithm for finding 1s in a list. The issue is that `any` is an O(N) operation so at every iteration of the loop, you're doing either N/2 or N operations. The loop runs log(N) times. There is a little math involved, but you can pretty easily show that this is an O(N*log(N)) algorithm, while simply using `inlist.index(1)` (or a basic for loop) you can find 1s in N operations.

However, to help you learn I went ahead and fixed your algorithm here is a working version, which passes the above tests :)

```
def binary_search(inList):
    low = 0
    high = len(inList)
    while low < high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        upper = inList[mid:high]
        lower = inList[low:mid]
        if any(lower):
            high = mid
        elif any(upper):
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            # Neither side has a 1
            return -1

    assert low == high
    return mid
```

The main problem with your version was that you were modifying low/high and modifying inlist at the same time. Because low/high are indices into inlist, when you modify inlist they no longer point to the right place.

Comment: I understand this is a bad algorithm for searching for a few 1's in a list. I'm just implementing this to get used to Python (afternoon 2 with it) and as a stepping stone to implementing a much better algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a simple test suite using `unittest` that can test the result for different inputs, it should be quite simple for this example.

This should get you started - try running this script (after modifying the import to import your binary search module), a google for `python unittest` should give you plenty of ideas on how you can extend this.

```
import unittest

from <your module> import binary_search

class TestBinarySearchForOne(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_small_range(self):
        self.assertEquals(1, binary_search(range(0, 2))

    def test_not_found(self):
        self.assertEquals(-1, binary_search([0, 4, 9, 190])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't suppose you have any idea why the code is currently giving me empty lists after 3 iterations?

Comment: Sorry I find that difficult to pick out, I am not so familiar with the algorithm. However, a fabulous technique for this is to write some unit tests that fail because of this (i.e. they expose the bug) and then you have the perfect scaffolding to help you work on finding a solution to the bug, and prove the bug has been eliminated when you have fixed it. Furthermore you can keep the tests around to verify in the future that the bug hasn't come back. Unit tests are wonderful like that!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do; you only need to change two lines in the "classic" algorithm, as given in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm):

```
def binary_search(inList):
    low = 0
    high = len(inList) - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = low + (high - low) // 2
        if any(inList[low:mid - 1]):    # <- this one
            high = mid - 1
        elif any(inList[mid + 1:high]): # <- this one
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            return mid
    return -1
```

This works for me:

```
>>> binary_search(l)
123
```